# Handling huge thirdparty api calls in laravel

Tags: laravel, api, command, laravel-artisan

I'm new to Laravel and I'm implementing a project. In my case, I have to call one trading API in the controller nearly 500 times to get all my data because of API restriction I can't request multiple datasets but one at a time, So to get 500 datasets I put that API call in a loop and the loop is taking way more time, is there any way to solve this like parallel executing the app API calls.

And also I tried putting the API call in command and calling artisan from controller inside the loop but it's also taking more time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a [queue](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues) so you can process multiple API calls in paralell, I recommend you to use [Laravel Horizon](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/horizon)

Comment: Horizon may be off-topic since it implies you are using Redis for the queues. You may need to mention that you need several workers to handle the `parallel` tasks